# Getting 3 frames side by side

Tags: css

I have a frame which is 760px wide.
I then have a div called main inside that which is 750px wide and has padding of 5px.

```
.main {
width:750px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
```

}

I then have a div inside that called latest which i want 3 side by side.

```
.latest {
width:240px;
padding:5px;
```

}

If I put float:left on the latest div, it ends up with them being outside of the main.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="latest">
        asdasdas
    </div>

    <div class="latest">
        asdasdas
    </div>

    <div class="latest">
        asdasdas
    </div>
</div>
```

The code i use to put it all together.
I cant think of anything else.
Thanks for reading, hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow: auto to the .main div.

More explanation here: http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Comment: And this is the answer! Cheers bud.
I will read that link to understand this attribute more, never used it before!

Answer (score 1):

```
.latest {
    width:240px;
    padding:5px;
    float: left;
}
```

something to read
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Read this,
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/clear.htm

This will probably solve your problem

add this in your main div

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and add this in your style

```
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: In my question, i wrote that if i put float:left, the three latest divs end up outside the main div.

Comment: I am not sure how you mean outside, could you make a screenshot?

Comment: I could do a screenshot, host it and link here?